# jQuery similar thing to selectmenu for anchor tags?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

We are reapplying the styles on our select menu like so:

`$('.select').selectmenu();`

This works great.. but we also need to do it on our anchor tags too.

These look like this:

`<a data-callback="Continue" data-theme="b" data-role="button" name="Continue" data-transition="pop" data-direction="reverse">Continue</a>`

How can we get jQuery mobile to apply the style to these elements too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('#dialogContainer a').button();`

This seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('.selectButton').button('refresh');
```

to more  information

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/buttons/buttons-methods.html